# didUpdateLocations not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm trying to get my current location, but the break point in didUpdateLocations is never being called.

LocationManager:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
```

I confirmed that location services and enabled and authorized.

Why is the locationManager delegate method not being called like it should?

Comment: had the same problem a couple of minutes ago, I had not done the `[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374216/didupdatelocation-method-never-called) that helped me

Comment: try to remove this line : `[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLDistanceFilterNone];` as you set setDesiredAccuracy twice, and make locationManager a property

Answer (score 69):

Furthermore in iOS8 you must have two extra things:

- Add a key to your `Info.plist` and request authorization from the location manager asking it to start.

  - `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
  - `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
- You need to request authorization for the corresponding location method.

  - `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`
  - `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`

Code example:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
// Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Source: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: perfect answer for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. There are some things missing. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26604933) works.

Comment: Please note that in iOS 11, a third key has to be supplied to your info.plist:

NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription

Answer (score 37):

When I had this problem, it was due to a threading issue.

Make sure, that all of these methods are called on the main thread.
It is very important, that not only the `startUpdatingLocation` method is called on the main thread, but the others as well.

You can force code to be run on the main thread by wrapping it inside

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});
```

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19041925/1984384).

Comment: I have the same issue as above, but when I use your solution, my button isn't clickable afterwards. It's odd.

Comment: Must have overlooked it... what button are you talking about?

Comment: From my experience, dispatch_async() is enough…
It may solve interface update issues - just guessing @dulax

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you added CLLocationManager as a property.

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Comment: Looks like this helped me - otherwise I kept getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the property was the solution for me, and good idea to check the Location Service is enabled:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If CLLocationManagerDelegate is set, MapView Delegate is also set

Also Check the location of the simulator, Click on Simulator > Debug > Location,
if it is none change into city run or freeway drive. Its worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that in iOS 11 and later, a third key has to be supplied to your info.plist: NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription

Answer (score 3):

You do have to tell the simulator what location to simulate. If you don't specify a location your `CLLocationManager` delegate methods will never get called. You can use the simulator menu Debug -> Location. Also in Xcode down by the debug area there's a little location arrow that appears when running the app from Xcode. You can use that to specify a GPX file to simulate motion (it's still not the same as the real device though).

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1073267#1073267

Answer (score 0):

My app started sometimes experiencing a multi-minute delay in the first call to `didUpdateLocations` after I had changed the `desiredAccuracy` attribute of my `CLLocationManager` to have a value of `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`:

```
myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer; 
[myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]; // Occasional long delay
```

After changing it back to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, the call to `didUpdateLocations` once again started always occurring immediately:

```
myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
[myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]; // Calls didUpdateLocations immediately
```