# CLLocationManager.requestLocation() takes about 10 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location

`CLLocationManager.requestLocation()` takes around 10 seconds to fire `didUpdateLocations` event.

Here are the attributes set for the `CLLocationManager`

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.requestLocation()
```

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation) this can take several seconds.

> This method returns immediately. Calling it causes the location manager to obtain a location fix (which may take several seconds) and call the delegate’s locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method with the result.

But can this take 10 long seconds? Or am I missing something?

Comment: (which may take several seconds). Make sure you update the UI from the main queue

Comment: It takes time to get an accurate location if the GPS isn't already run in. If a location can't be found it may take longer than 10 seconds before giving up.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. 
@SausageMachine I'm not complaining, I'm wondering how apps like Google Maps get location around 3 seconds using the same `While using` location access level.
@All genius down voters, I'm asking this because i haven't seen an app taking this much of time to get location. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19624719/12484

Answer (score 16):

If you switch out the

```
locationManager.requestLocation()
```

for

```
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

then `didUpdateLocations` will start firing immediately. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @bradchattergoon. I'm doing this every time the app goes back to the foreground. For my use case, this was not sufficient, so I've added locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() before locationManager.startUpdatingLocation().

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR

**requestLocation()** is a convenient method provided by Apple which under the hood will run **startUpdatingLocation()** , retrieve multiple location data, and select the most accurate one to pass to delegate, and call **stopUpdatingLocation()**

This process can take up to 10 seconds (which is around the timeout limit) if it can't decide which location data is the best.

Answer (score 2):

I changed `.desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` and my `.requestLocation()` now returns the position immediately

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a false premise. *That Google is always faster*. I'm guessing that your building app from scratch and the app has no access to cache. Otherwise GoogleMaps can also sometimes take more than 3 seconds. Obviously I don't know the exact specifics but I just think when you're using GoogleMaps you're using it as a user and now when you're developing your own app you're thinking about it as a developer ie you're being more meticulous about it.

Also to have the best of comparisons make sure you set your `desiredAccuracy` to `BestForNavigation`, `distanceFilter` to `0` and `activityType` to `.automotive`. That's normally what navigation apps are doing.

Leo's comment is also important: *Make sure you update the UI from the main queue*

And as mentioned by both highly experienced in Core-Location users: [programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19051459/5175709) and [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499541/cllocationmanager-requestlocation-takes-about-10-seconds/52466936#comment66316926_39499541):

*When you call `startUpdatingLocation` on the location manager you must give it time to get a position. You should not immediately call `stopUpdatingLocation`. We let it run for a maximum of 10 seconds or until we get a non-cached high accuracy location.*

Answer (score 1):

I found the following line in my Console logs:

> Ignoring requestLocation due to ongoing location.

No idea what's going on. My app doesn't call `startUpdatingLocation()` at all. But when I keep the app running I can see that `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` is called periodically.

Once I put `stopUpdatingLocation()` in front of the `requestLocation()` it's as fast as expected:

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.requestLocation()
```